# official authoritative source for bacterial shape classification

Tags: bacteriology

I'm a bit disappointed but after several hours of search, I could not find an official authoritative source for bacterial shape classification. I find a lot, I mean a lot of links but no original sources, even on  [Microbiology society no source...](https://microbiologyonline.org/about-microbiology/introducing-microbes/bacteria).

I believe a convention, workshop or another authoritative source must at one point have worked on this matter...

Comment: Oxford English Dictionary? Or, as Steve Jobs said about pornography, I know it when I see it.

Comment: Shape based classification is somewhat obsolete.

Comment: I am well aware that phenotypic classification for prokaryote is obsolete, but I would like to find the source that describes the official acknowledged bacterial shapes.